# Эксперименты с опциями оптимизации g++

Tags: g++

Решил проверить влияние опций оптимизации компилятора на практике. 
Есть два файла (code2.cpp code3.cpp) с одинаковым кодом.

```
#include <iostream>

void printer(const int i){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)   printer(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Я хочу посмотреть ассемблерный код в двух разных случаях. Первый случай, это применение компилятора  с такими опциями g++ -S -O2 code2.cpp. А второй случай такой g++ -S -O3 code3.cpp. В итоге я ожидал что файл который получится от использования опции -O3 будет больше, потому что там осуществится развертка цикла.

Результаты получились такие (файл с именем 2 это то что получилось из code2.cpp, 3 из *3.срр)

```
26/05/2018  10:37               169 code2.cpp
26/05/2018  11:30             3,865 code2.s
26/05/2018  10:34               169 code3.cpp
26/05/2018  11:30             3,865 code3.s
               4 файлов          8,068 байт
               2 папок  158,534,213,632 байт свободно
```

Т.е. цикл не развернулся, а я очень хотел) Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Потому что параметр `-o` задает имя выходного файла (поэтому и получились файлы 2 и 3). А оптимизацию вы вообще не использовали, она включается ключом `-O` (большая буква O)

Comment: Спасибо. Изменение регистра опции изменило определение файла. Теперь всё как и положено, касаемо форматов. Но оптимизация всё равно не сработала) (изменил вопрос)

Comment: Не знаю почему у вас такие результаты. у меня ваш пример на O2 и O3 дает абсолютно разные результаты. разворачивания цикла конечно нет, потому что ни одному компилятору не придет в голову разворачивать цикл из 100 итераций

Comment: У меня O3 просто вставил все содержимое printer прямо в цикл, что явно выгоднее, чем разворачивать цикл и делать подряд несколько call функции

Comment: Компилятор не развернул цикл, хотя я его попросил об этом при помощи опции (я так понимаю опция является указанием к действию, а не как рекомендация (как с ключевым словом инлайн для функции))

Comment: Опция O3 просто устанавливает более глубокий, чем при O2 анализ и соответственно более сильную оптимизацию. Есть сотни способов оптимизации, какие будут применены в конкретном случае компилятор решит сам. Да, при включении O3 он _может_ задействовать разворачивание циклов (в отличие от O2), там, где это уместно. В случае с call это не уместно, inline подстановка тела функции гораздо эффективнее. Обратите особое внимание на все опции включаемые O3 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html среди них есть и inline подстановка

Comment: И любые ключи оптимизации - это _рекомендации_, а не _требования_

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее)